# Resyncing and deleting chaindata directory

Tags: go-ethereum, mist, synchronization

I'm about to do a resync of the blockchain but as I was deleting my chaindata directory from:

```
~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata
```

I noticed there was also another chaindata directory located here:

```
~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata
```

This seems a bit confusing to me. Am I supposed to delete both? What is the difference between the two? I'm not sure if the chaindata directory existed before I updated geth to 1.5.9 today. I'm using Mist if that helps.

Answer (score 2):

The location of the `chaindata` folder was changed in version [1.5.0](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.5.0) of Geth (I *think* - I can't immediately see it in the changeset... ).

It was moved from `~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata` to `~/Library/Ethereum/geth/chaindata`, with equivalent changes being made to the Windows and Linux locations.

It's safe to remove them both. `geth removedb` may only remove the directory from the new location, in which case you should manually remove it from the old location as well using `rm -rf ~/Library/Ethereum/chaindata`.

Answer (score 1):

I think instead of deleting it manually you want to use

```
geth removedb
```

Sorry I can't answer the rest.